# How smart is lazy evaluation len(obj) == 1 will it count all?

Tags: python

Would python count all items for length or just understand and stop if 2nd item is found?

```
if len(obj) == 1: ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this resource https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity the time complexity for `len` function is O(1), meaning that python already knows how many elements a common "array" data type has.

Comment: It depends on what `obj` is. Lists, tuples, sets and all basic data type you find in python will store the length inside the object, so it will just compare this value with `1`. On custom objects, you cannot be sure.

Comment: Beware though of this pitfall: len([1,2/3,2/0]). What do you think it returns?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are thinking of `obj` as a list of items, in other case I didn't quite get your question so ignore my answer.

Python stores the lenght of a list in its internal data structure, so it does not need to go through it every time you call `len`, it can just read the value stored.

Comment: @user3379328 So as others pointed out, it is true for lists, dictionaries and tuples. However for other iterables, for example custom ones, it depends on the implementation of `__len__` provided.

Answer (score 2):

None of the Python builtin objects iterate to find `len`. They all keep track when you add/remove items, so it's O(1)

If you define a `__len__` method on your own class that doesn't keep track of it's length, you might do this

```
def __len__(self):
    return sum(1 for i in self)
```

Which can't shortcircuit - it has to iterate right to the end.

It's a bunch more complicated to make a short circuiting version, but it can be done.